# Inserir elemento Fila C

Tags: c

Galera como faço para "Inserir um elemento (retornando 1 caso a inserção tenha tido sucesso, e -1 caso contrário) em uma Fila"

Eu fiz isso, o que falta:

```
void enfilerar(tipo_fila *fila, int valor)
{
    if (fila->fim<TAM_FILA)
    {
        fila->fim++;
        fila->fila[fila->fim]=valor;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fila cheia!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está a esturtura `tipo_fila`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer de 2 maneiras:

**1 -**

```
int enfilerar(tipo_fila *fila, int valor)
{
    if (fila->fim<TAM_FILA)
    {
        fila->fim++;
        fila->fila[fila->fim]=valor;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fila cheia!");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**2 - (Recomendado)**

```
int enfilerar(tipo_fila *fila, int valor)
{
    int retorno = 0;

    if (fila->fim<TAM_FILA)
    {
        fila->fim++;
        fila->fila[fila->fim]=valor;
        retorno = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fila cheia!");
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

Ambas maneiras irão funcionar, entretanto é recomendado retornar valores em apenas 1 momento da função. A segunda maneira segue essa recomendação.